# Increasing the scale of a flag cloth simulation makes it fly much stronger

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

When I increase the size of the flags, they fly much faster.  Is there a solution to this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What flags exactly are you talking about? There doesn't seem to be sufficient information. Is it a flag simulation in blender or?

Comment: https://youtu.be/6yxGej1wFC8

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the software you are using. So, I'm not sure if I can help. My apologies.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Blender? https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Because I'm trying to do it in blender?

Comment: I'm doing it using cloth physics

Comment: Can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello Güray  .. Forgive me if this just a problem with idiomatic language, but we have no way of telling what 'the' flags are, without reading your mind. Please include a description of the simulation you are running. There may be too many settings to achieve more than a sketch, in writing and pictures, fair enough. In that case, please add a share  your file, stripped down to the part that matters, on https://blend-exchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have a cloth that is very thin and light. Now you have the same thing but bigger and still same weight. That cloth will rip apart with these harsh winds. Naturally the cloth should be sturdier accompanied with higher weight as it gets bigger. Try adjusting the stiffness and weight settings.

[image]